# Chrome plugin IFrame empty

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, plugins

I have the following script that is executed from the js of my plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<div id=\"phone\"></div>");
    $("#phone").load(chrome.extension.getURL("DialogBox.html"), PhoneJs);
});
```

Is is appending a div to the current page and then adding html to the div.
In this DialogBox html, I have an "IFrame" element that I am trying to set the source from the "PhoneJs" like this :

```
$("#framePhone").attr('src', chrome.extension.getURL("Content.html"));
```

Src is loading and it shows :

```
<iframe id="framePhone" src="chrome-extension://gmecifkccnidnkoaenkmbbhhcebbgdbi/Content.html">
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

My problem is that it is not supposed to have an empty body or head, the source does not seems to load and I feel like it is a "about:blank" src instead.